# .htaccess same rewrite rule with different attributes

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I couldn't figure out how am I supposed to separate these two rules.

```
RewriteRule ^products.php/([^/\.]+)/?$ products.php?type=product&product_id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^products.php/([^/\.]+)/?$ products.php?type=product&category=$1 [L]
```

They both go to the same page the only difference is their attributes and because of that they overlap each other. it never even goes to the second rule.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

These are the actual url's I'm using

```
http://localhost/mg_com_tr/products/accesories
http://localhost/mg_com_tr/products/65
```

Comment: how it is supposed to know, the paramter you are passing is product_id or category, it will obviously go to the first rule

Comment: better introduce a third param to indicate whether it is product_id or category

Answer (score 0):

Change the two rewrite rules to

```
RewriteRule ^products\.php/(\d+)/?$ products.php?type=product&product_id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^products\.php/(\w+)/?$ products.php?type=product&category=$1 [NC,L]
```